# Using two delegates

Tags: ios, iphone, background, delegates, notifications

I am new to iPhone programming. I want to call a function which belongs to one of my views in MyAppDelegate. I want to do this because I cannot find any ApplicationDidEnterBackground() event in view. 
   So, basically I want to call view's function when the application is minimized. I did try using delegate. However I cannot find how to use two delegates as MyAppDelegate already has one. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general design pattern is, if you have multiple interested parties in an event, don't use delegates but notifications. In this case, you should register a `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` in your `-init` method of every class where you wanna handle the event:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(didEnterBackground)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                           object:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];
```

Then write a `-(void)didEnterBackground` method with your code. In your `-dealloc` method, make sure to unregister the notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                              object:nil];
```

Also, be aware that this code requires iOS 4.x or higher. If you want to maintain iOS 3 compatibility you've to check the availability first:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(applicationState)]) {
    // register UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
}
```